# Postgres query with pandas - add explicit type casts

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I am trying to query a postgres database via pandas connection, passing the query as a string, like so:

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost:5432/FAPESP-Covid19')

PacientesStat = psql.read_sql("SELECT CD_Municipio, Min(2021-aa_nasc), Max(2021-aa_nasc), Count(*) Tot\
    FROM Pacientes\
    GROUP BY 1\
    ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST;", engine)
```

But I get the error:

```
LINE 1: SELECT CD_Municipio, Min(2021-aa_nasc), Max(2021-aa_nasc), C...
                                     ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I see that aa_nasc column is set as CHAR.

Ho do I fix the types here?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
UPDATE pacientes SET aa_nasc = NULL WHERE aa_nasc = 'AAAA' OR aa_nasc = 'YYYY';
ALTER TABLE pacientes ALTER COLUMN aa_nasc TYPE INT USING aa_nasc::integer;
```